# Como guardar progreso, base de datos, sharepreferences, etc de una aplicación en Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase

tengo una duda y no se por donde tirar. Tengo una app que contiene una base de datos sqlite y algunas sharepreferences.

Mi duda es la siguiente:

¿Como hago para que el usuario mantenga sus Sharepreferences y base de datos si cambia de telefono?

¿hay alguna forma de subir estos datos (archivo *.db) por ejemplo a Firebase y poder sincronizarlos?

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Que has realizado , agregalo por favor

Comment: Para que mantenga es guardando en la nube y en el nuevo telefono sincronizar con la nube todas las app lo hacen asi. Subir archivos firebase tiene el storage que permite subida de cualquier archivo, puedes descargarlos guardarlos en el telefono.